# concatenation jsx with Link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a map function I try to concatenate obj.id to a Link component of react-router. It doesn't work like this?

```
<Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>
```

I even tried

```
<Link to=`/item/edit/${obj._id}`>Edit</Link>
```

No luck. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the JavaScript between curly braces. See the documentation on JavaScript expressions: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions

Either like this:

```
<Link to={"/item/edit/" + obj._id}>Edit</link>
```

or like this:

```
<Link to={`/item/edit/${obj._id}`}>Edit</Link>
```